# How to highlight specific text in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

In a `RichTextBox` control, I am trying to highlight a specific text in RED color as a result from a Regex match.

Sample:

This text statement works fine and highlights the 'Deans' in red shade:

> select top 10 * from client where MailName='Deans'

This text statement works fine also and highlights the code in red shade:

> select top 10 * from client where MailName='De a ns'

But this statement fails:

> select top 10 * from client where MailName='Deans '

It fails because there is space in between the single quotes, it throws an exception on the line making the start TextRange at

```
TextRange result = new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(word.Length));
```

The exception says:

> invalid parameter position 2.

Please suggest me a solution. Where am I making a mistake?

Here is the code snippet:

```
string StringFromRichTextBox(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart,      
                rtb.Document.ContentEnd);

    return textRange.Text;
}

private void TextChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextRange documentRange = new TextRange(txtQueries.Document.ContentStart, txtQueries.Document.ContentEnd);
        documentRange.ClearAllProperties();

    MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(StringFromRichTextBox(txtQueries), @"'([^']*)'");
    for (int z = 0; z < match.Count; z++)
    {
        CheckKeyword(documentRange, match[z].ToString().Trim());
    }
}

private void CheckKeyword(TextRange textRange, string word)
{
    //txtQueries.TextChanged -= this.TextChangedEventHandler;
    if (textRange.Text.Contains(word))
    {
        int offset = textRange.Text.IndexOf(word);
        if (offset < 0)
        {
            return;
        }// Not found
        else
        {
            // Try to select the text as a contiguous range
            for (TextPointer start = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(offset); start != textRange.End; start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(1))
            {
                try
                {
                    TextRange result = new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(word.Length));
                    if (result != null && result.Text == word)  
                    {
                        result.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //txtQueries.TextChanged += this.TextChangedEventHandler;
}
```

Error Message:

> Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: position2
>   at System.Windows.Documents.TextRange..ctor(TextPointer position1, TextPointer position2)

Comment: Which line of code throwing the exception? Also please post exact exception message you are getting for quick understanding of problem.

Comment: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: position2 at System.Windows.Documents.TextRange..ctor(TextPointer position1, TextPointer position2)

Comment: Since the problem is clear from the exception, did you try debugging with a breakpoint what value is passed to `position2` in your code? I guess the line: `TextRange result = new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(word.Length));` could be the culprit.

Comment: I don't have the fix to this specific case.

Comment: Did u try this case - select top 10 * from client where MailName='Deans  ' . TextChangedEventHandler is fired when you type something in the RichTextBoX. It is wired with the control from the XAML code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution :: Added 4 to the offset length to account for special invisible characters coming up with space in richtextbox.

```
    var length = word.Length;
                // Try to select the text as a contiguous range
                for (TextPointer start = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(offset); start != textRange.End; start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(1))
                {
                    try
                    {

                        TextRange result = new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(word.Contains(" ") ? word.Length + 4: word.Length)); //Added 4 to the offset length to account for special invisible characters coming up with space in richtext box
                        if (result.Text.Trim() == word.Trim())  
                        {
                            result.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a LOT of trouble wrestling with this issue as well! After lots of wtf's with `GetPositionAtOffset` I came up with this method to get accurate `TextPointer`s when searching in a `RichTextBox`:

```
public static TextRange FindStringRangeFromPosition(TextPointer position, string str) {
     //what makes this work is checking the PointerContext so you avoid the markup characters   
     while (position != null) {
            if (position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text) {
                string textRun = position.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);

                // Find the starting index of any substring that matches "str".
                int indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(str);
                if (indexInRun >= 0) {
                //since we KNOW we're in a text section we can find the endPointer by the str.Length now
                    return new TextRange(position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun), position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun + str.Length));
                }
            }
            position = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }

        // position will be null if "str" is not found.
        return null;
    }
```